# How to click on a object or fire event in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am facing a strnge issue, when i am trying to click on "C" link displayed in the attachment. Please observe the link description marked in Red.[image]

I tried below it didnt helped.

```
WebElement ele=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul[@class='whp-rolodex']/li[contains(.,'C')]"));
ele.click();
```

Then i tried with Actions, but didnt help

```
Actions action=new Actions(driver);
action.moveToElement(ele).click().perform();
action.click().perform(); //this also didnt help
```

Then tried with JavaScriptExecutor, this also didnt help

```
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", ele);
```

I kept ele.isDisplayed() before these clicks and everywhere it shows true.

Can someone help where i am going wrong, are there any better ways.

Using FF 40, selenium webdriver 2.47

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because your xpath is wrong. C contains in "a" tag while you are trying to find c in "li" tag.

use xpath something like this

```
//ul[@class='whp-rolodex']/li[3]/a[contains(.,'C')]
```

Comment: Thanks subham pointing out. I am over conscious as when i ran the xpath(//ul[@class='whp-rolodex']/li[contains(.,'C')]) in console it pointedthe right element, so i thought i am correct, but ur solution perfectly clicked on the element.

Answer (score 1):

While @Shubham's point is perfectly valid, I would simplify it down to using a "link text" locator:

```
driver.findElement(by.linkText("C"));
```

which looks quite simple and readable.

Comment: This is simple and helped me. I am over conscious to look at events and thought "linkText" may not help.

Comment: Thanx @alecxe for your support and kind words :)